# Error al compilar mi proyecto para produccion en Angula Cli 6

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

Tengo un error al compilar mi proyecto para subir a produccion:

```
src\app\landing\landing.component.html(185,71): : Property 'textoland' does not exist on type 'LandingComponent'.
```

Contact.ts

```
export class Contact {
    public $key: string;
    public nombreland: string;
    public emailland: string;
    public textoland: string;
    public apellidoland: string;
    public telefonoContact: string;
}
```

contact.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Contact } from '../model/contact';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactService {

  Contacto: Contact = new Contact();
  emailMg: AngularFireList<any>;
  formMensaje: Contact = new Contact();
  constructor(private firebase: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  enviarEmail(emailMg: Contact){


   console.log(emailMg.emailland);

   this.emailMg = this.firebase.list('emailMensaje');
   if (emailMg) {
    this.emailMg.push({
      nombre: emailMg.nombreland,
      email: emailMg.emailland,
      texto: emailMg.textoland

    });
    alert("Mensaje enviado! En breve nos contactaremos con usted!")
  }
  }

  enviarEmailModal(emailMg: Contact){


    console.log(emailMg.emailland);

    this.emailMg = this.firebase.list('emailMensaje');
    if (emailMg) {
     this.emailMg.push({
       nombre: emailMg.nombreland,
       email: emailMg.emailland,
       texto: emailMg.textoland,
       telefono: emailMg.telefonoContact

     });
     alert("Mensaje enviado! En breve nos contactaremos con usted!")
   }
   }


}
```

landing.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactService } from '../service/contact.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-landing',
    templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./landing.component.scss']
})

export class LandingComponent implements OnInit {
  focus: any;
  focus1: any;

  constructor( public getContactService: ContactService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  sendEmail(sendEmailFormat?: NgForm){
    this.getContactService.enviarEmail(sendEmailFormat.value);
    sendEmailFormat.reset();
  }    
}
```

No puedo ejecutar `ng build --prod` por que me muestra el error que mostre al principio

landing.component.html

```
<div class="page-header" data-parallax="true" style="background-image: url('/landing/assets/img/daniel-olahh.jpg');">
    <div class="filter"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="motto text-center">
            <h1>Plan Premium Admin</h1>
            <h3>Diseño que se adapta a todos los dispositivos</h3>
            <h4>Ejemplo exposicion de productos Jhonn Dere</h4>
            <br />

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="section text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 mr-auto ml-auto">
                <h2 class="title">Aplicaciones Especiales</h2>
                <h5 class="description">Dentro de esta sección de Aplicaciones especiales 
                    usted podrá encontrar aireadores, pulverizadores/aspersoras y top dressers.
                     Uno para cada necesidad.Éstas son algunas de las soluciones que John Deere 
                     ofrece para superar el desafío de cuidar el césped. Equipos especialmente diseñados, con la calidad
                     y la precisión que sólo una empresa líder puede garantizar.</h5>
                <br>
                <a href="#paper-kit" class="btn btn-info btn-round">Ver detalles</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/><br/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="info">
                    <div class="icon icon-info">
                       <img src="/landing/assets/img/mapa.png" width="200" height="200" alt="mapa">
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h4 class="info-title">Donde comprar</h4>
                        <p class="description">Encuentra nuestros locales alojados en todo el pais.</p>
                        <a target="__blank" href="https://dealerlocator.deere.com/servlet/country=AR?locale=es_AR" class="btn btn-link btn-info">Ver mapa</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="info">
                    <div class="icon icon-info">
                            <iframe width="250" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/d0F8qL2BEKI" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h4 class="info-title">Posventa</h4>
                        <p>Experimenta la evolucion de la posventa</p>
                        <a target="__blank" href="https://www.deere.com.ar/es/repuestos-servicio/" class="btn btn-link btn-info">Ir a posventa</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="info">
                    <div class="icon icon-info">
                            <img src="/landing/assets/img/repuestos.png" width="200" height="200" alt="mapa">
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h4 class="info-title">Buscador de repuestos</h4>
                        <p>Buscar por pin, modelo, equipo, etc...</p>
                        <a target="__blank" href="https://www.deere.com.ar/es/repuestos-servicio/repuestos/" class="btn btn-link btn-info">Buscar</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="info">
                    <div class="icon icon-info">
                            <iframe width="250" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GdMJbBAtzso" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h4 class="info-title">Equipos usados</h4>
                        <p>Find unique and handmade delightful designs related items directly from our sellers.</p>
                        <a target="__blanck" href="http://www.machinefinder.com.ar/" class="btn btn-link btn-info">Buscar</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="section section-dark text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="title">Hablemos de nosotros</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card card-profile card-plain">
                    <div class="card-avatar">
                        <a href="#avatar"><img src="/landing/assets/img/faces/clem-onojeghuo-3.jpg" alt="..."></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <a href="#paper-kit">
                            <div class="author">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Carlos</h4>
                                <h6 class="card-category">Ingeniero agronomo</h6>
                            </div>
                        </a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-center">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-just-icon btn-neutral"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-just-icon btn-neutral"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-just-icon btn-neutral"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card card-profile card-plain">
                    <div class="card-avatar">
                        <a href="#avatar"><img src="/landing/assets/img/faces/joe-gardner-2.jpg" alt="..."></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <a href="#paper-kit">
                            <div class="author">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Sofia</h4>
                                <h6 class="card-category">Diseñadora industrial</h6>
                            </div>
                        </a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-center">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-just-icon btn-neutral"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-just-icon btn-neutral"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-just-icon btn-neutral"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card card-profile card-plain">
                    <div class="card-avatar">
                        <a href="#avatar">
                            <img src="/landing/assets/img/faces/erik-lucatero-2.jpg"  alt="..."></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <a href="#paper-kit">
                            <div class="author">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Estefania</h4>
                                <h6 class="card-category">Ingeniera electronica</h6>
                            </div>
                        </a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-center">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-just-icon btn-neutral"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-just-icon btn-neutral"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-just-icon btn-neutral"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="section landing-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 mr-auto ml-auto">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Contacto</h2>
                    <form #sendEmailVar="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="sendEmail(sendEmailVar)" class="contact-form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label>Nombre</label>
                                <div class="input-group" [ngClass]="{'input-group-focus':focus===true}">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="nc-icon nc-single-02"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" id="nombreland" [(ngModel)]="nombreland" name="nombreland" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" (focus)="focus=true" (blur)="focus=false" >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <div class="input-group" [ngClass]="{'input-group-focus':focus1===true}">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                      <span class="input-group-text">  <i class="nc-icon nc-email-85"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" id="emailland" [(ngModel)]="emailland" name="emailland"  class="form-control" placeholder="Email" (focus)="focus1=true" (blur)="focus1=false" >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <label>Mensaje</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="textoland" [(ngModel)]="textoland" name="textoland"  rows="4" placeholder="Mi consulta es....."></textarea>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4 mr-auto ml-auto">
                                <button  type="submit"  class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-fill">Enviar consulta</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nahuel, el problema parecería estar en el landing.component.html.  ¿Podrías copiar el código de ese HTML?

Comment: @GustavoCantero No me doy cuenta si esta en el HTML, solo que no entiendo por que el error no es muy especifico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la linea 185 de landing.component.html tenés el siguiente binding

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="textoland" [(ngModel)]="textoland"...
```

Pero en el código de landing.component.ts no tenés ninguna propiedad textoland.  Por lo que ven el código creo que en realidad el binding debe ser con getContactService.Contacto.textoland, ya que estás inyectando en la clase un objeto ContactService que es quien tiene la clase Contact.

¡Suerte!

Comment: no creo por que  consumiendo el servicio desde contact.service                               `ngOnInit() {}
  sendEmail(sendEmailFormat?: NgForm){

    this.getContactService.enviarEmail(sendEmailFormat.value);
    sendEmailFormat.reset();
    
  }` el servicio this.getContactService.enviarEmail() contiene el modelo de la clase Contact.

Comment: Pero el problema es el [(ngModel)]="textoland", ya que la clase LandingComponent  no tiene una propiedad llamada textoland.

Comment: Gracias @gustavo problema solucionado!

Comment: Me alegro Nahuel.  Por favor marca la respuesta como útil si te sirvió.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias @Gustavo el error estaba por que no estaba creando la propiedad en LandingComponent

```
  public nombreland: ContactService;
  public emailland: ContactService;
  public textoland: ContactService;
  public telefonoContact: ContactService;
```

**Solucionado el problema!!**